# Converting web.confg into .htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, web-config

I am trying to convert from using web.config on IIS to .htaccess on apache.
Although, i've got everything working, but got stuck on one thing.

```
<rule name="Imported Rule 2">
 <match url="^blog/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)(|/)$" ignoreCase="false" />
  <action type="Rewrite" url="index.php?url=blog&amp;id={R:1}" appendQueryString="false" />
</rule>
```

I am trying to convert the above code into .htaccess.
If anybody could help, it would be gratefully appreciated.

Comment: I'm surprised you didn't try this yourself. Once you learn how mod_rewrite works, this conversion is very simple.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add this config to .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^blog/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)(|/)$ index.php?url=blog&id=$1
```